# Subtract two matrices using linux script

Tags: linux, bash, matrix

I would like to subtract the values of two matrices using a script. My files have .dat or .ext extension. I believe that there is a simple command that I can use in a script, with which I can do that. I have  searched a lot, but the only thing that I find is the command diff, with which I can only find and print the elements that are different between two files.
 My files have in the first column the date and in the rest columns values. I want to write in another file the outcome of the subtraction of these two matrices, but keeping the first column as it is. Thank you.

The structure of the files is like this:

**File1**:

```
1890   0.6  0.7  0.0

1910   0.3  0.4  0.2

2100   0.2  0.9  0.3
```

**File2**:

```
1890  0.3  0.3   0.0

1910  0.2  0.2   0.1

2100  0.1  0.1   0.1
```

I want to end up with file3

```
Fil3=File1-File2
```

**File3**:

```
1890  0.3  0.4  0.0

1910  0.1  0.2  0.1

2100  0.1  0.8  0.2
```

I tried this in my script: `File3 = $File1 - $File2 | cat $File3`

Comment: what is "abstract"ing a matrix?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)

Comment: i know what is matrix. But what is abstracting a matrix?

Comment: Probably my English are not very good. I do not how to say this: A - B

Comment: Can you please supply some sample data

Comment: Show the parts of the file and show the parts of your code that are relevant to this question.

Comment: Your explanation is very vague. Providing us with an example or and extract from the files will help us better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry, I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

file1="file1.txt"
file2="file2.txt"
file3="file3.txt"

echo "Reading input files"
readarray -t mat1 < "$file1" || exit 1
readarray -t mat2 < "$file2" || exit 1

echo "Creating result"
>| "$file3" || exit 1

# Line number
n1=${#mat1[*]}
n2=${#mat2[*]}
((n = n1<n2 ? n1:n2))

for ((i=0; i<n; i++)); do
    line1=(${mat1[i]})
    line2=(${mat2[i]})

    line3=(${line1[0]})

    for ((j=1; j<=3; j++)); do
        line3+=($(echo "${line1[j]}-${line2[j]}"|bc))
    done 

    echo "${line3[@]}" >> "$file3"
done

echo "done"
exit 0
```

Comment: `bc` doesn't print `0.5` but `.5`. How to get `0.5` ?

Comment: Thank you very much Edouard Thiel, it is what i was looking for. I also found some minutes ago a solution using awk from the user000001 : paste file{1,2} | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) printf "%s ", ($i==$i+0)?$i-$(i+NF/2):$i; print ""}'. I just repeat it as a comment in case that someone sees this post.

Answer (score 1):

Linux script ?
It could be python, perl, shell, bash or ruby ..etc scripts.

I recommend using python with numpy :

But before you should read the first and the second file where you have your matrices to local variables in your script.

Your files should respect this format:

```
[[0, 1, 3],
[0, 1, 2],
[0, 1, 0]]
```

and your python script should look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpuy as np

val1 = ''.join(open('file1', 'r').readlines())
val2 = ''.join(open('file2', 'r').readlines())

mat1 = np.matrix(val1)
mat2 = np.matrix(val2)

#I am not sure about this but try it
mat3 = mat1 - mat2
```

You can also consider reading files to array, with the following array format:

```
((2,3), (3, 5))
```

e.g :

```
mat1 = np.array( val1 )
mat2 = np.array( val2 )
print (mat1-mat2)
```

If your not familiar with python, go [to](http://www.learnpython.org/) or search some beginners' tutorials.